# Calculate the sum of values in a linked list (masm) *follow up

Tags: assembly, masm

So I'm pretty new to assembly language and I was hoping I could get some help. I've written a function that adds up all the values in an integer array and produces the sum. Now I want to alter the function so that it uses a linked list instead such that the sum of all values in a linked list is returned. I'm still a beginner so I'm still learning the MASM but this is what I've written for the function that finds the sum of all values in an array:

```
 PUSH EBX
        PUSH ECX
        PUSH EDX
        PUSH ESI
        PUSH EDI

        MOV EBX, Arr
        MOV ECX, len




        mov eax, 0; sum
        mov ecx, 0; i
        mov ESI, len

FOR_EXPR:
        cmp ecx, esi
        jge END_FOR

        mov edx, dword ptr[ebx+ecx*4]
        add eax, edx

        inc ecx
        jmp FOR_EXPR
END_FOR:


        POP EDI
        POP ESI
        POP EDX
        POP ECX
        POP EBX
```

The new function will pass the head of the linked list in as a parameter: int function(struct Node *start).

Comment: How is this a follow-up?

Comment: People asked how the linked list was being presented on the last post. I should have wrote "*revised" instead of followup.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Calculate the sum of values in a linked list (masm)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22263349/calculate-the-sum-of-values-in-a-linked-list-masm)

Comment: No, you should have edited the original question.

Answer (score 0):

For the array example, you can put the fixed jump before the loop and the conditional jump at the end of loop:

```
        .model  FLAT
        .data
array   dd      1,2,3,4
len     dd      4

        .code
_main   proc    near
;       ...    
        push    ebx
        push    ecx
        push    edx
        push    esi
        push    edi
        lea     ebx, array
        mov     esi, len
        mov     eax, 0  ; sum
        mov     ecx, 0  ; i
        jmp     for1
for0:   mov     edx, [ebx+ecx*4]
        add     eax, edx
        inc     ecx
for1:   cmp     ecx, esi
        jl      for0
        pop     edi
        pop     esi
        pop     edx
        pop     ecx
        pop     ebx
;       ...
```

Answer (score 0):

For a linked list, here is enough of an example to show the syntax:

```
        .model FLAT
node    struct
next    dd      ?
value   dd      ?
node    ends

        .data
list0   node    {offset list1,1}
list1   node    {offset list2,2}
list2   node    {offset list3,3}
list3   node    {0           ,4}

        .code
_main   proc    near
;       ...
        push    ebx
        push    ecx
        push    edx
        push    esi
        push    edi
        lea     ebx, list0
;       ...
        add     eax,node.value[ebx]
;       ...
```